# Proof of Cohomology class of a single point manifold

Tags: abstract-algebra, geometry, differential

I have been trying to find a proof that the de Rham Cohomology group for a single point is equal to:

$H^{k}_{dR}=\mathbb{R}$ when $k=0$ and $H^{k}_{dR}=0$ when $k>0$.

I am sure this result is correct, but it seems to be quoted in many places almost religiously without proof; as though the results is obvious. If it is obvious, I cannot see it. Can anyone on here provide a proof of this result. I have searched extensively for one but cannot find one. It is quite fundamental in that a single point is a very simple example of a manifold. Thus I hope this question is useful in the community.

Comment: It is a bit of an exaggeration saying that this result doesn't appear anywhere. Even if a textbook does not explicitly calculate the cohomology of a point, any textbook that discusses the de-Rham cohomology shows that $H^0(M)$ is the number of connected components and that $H^k(M) = 0$ if $k > \dim M$ and this two facts already calculate the cohomology of a point.

Answer (score 2):

Since $M = \{ \text{pt} \}$ is a zero-dimensional manifold, there are no $k$ forms on $M$ for $k > 0$. The $0$-forms on $M$ are by definition smooth real valued functions on $M$ and, in our case they are identified naturally with the real numbers (each function is determined uniquely by where it sends the point to) so the de-Rham complex is

$$ 0 \rightarrow \underbrace{\mathbb{R}}_{\Omega^0(M)} \rightarrow \underbrace{0}_{\Omega^1(M)} \rightarrow \dots $$

Hence, $H_{dR}^k(M) = 0$ for $k > 0$ and $H_{dR}^0(M) = \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Yes I part got the idea already. I can see that for a point, with k=0, we can assign this point any real number and so we may have $H^{0}_{dR}=\mathbb{R}$. What I don't get is why  $H^{k}_{dR}=0$ for $k>0$. The problem I have is that it seems naively to me that there can be no Cartan derivative on $H^{0}_{dR}=\mathbb{R}$ since the function is only defined at a point. Isn't differentiation meaningless on a single point? In my ignorance this make me think the set $Z$ of closed forms and the set $B$ of exact forms both empty sets; i.e. there are no forms for k > 1? Where am I going wrong?

Comment: A $1$-form on $M = \{p\}$ is the same as a linear functional $\omega \colon T_p M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Since $T_p M = \{ 0 \}$ is zero dimensional, the only map which you have anyway is the zero map which and so $\Omega^1(M) = \{ 0 \}$ is a zero-dimensional space (it cannot be an empty set, it is always a vector space). The zero form is always closed and exact. Similarly for $\Omega^k(M)$ with $k > 1$.

Comment: I never thought of a tangent space to a point before, but I can see that this would work. 0 works as a basis for 0D vector space because $a\cdot 0 +b\cdot 0=0$. And a linear functional acting on $0$ has to return the value of zero for the usual reason that $f\left ( 0 \right )=f\left ( \lambda 0 \right )=\lambda f\left ( 0 \right )\Rightarrow f\left ( 0 \right )=0$. I guess you don't need to invoke a Cartan derivative if you look at it this way. I may not have got this right, but thanks for the advice.